# 404 error when making POST request to Ruby on Rails app with CSRF protection

Tags: python, python-requests, csrf-token

So there's [this](https://anystyle.io/) open-source application which parses citation strings into BibTex format and I'm attempting to use Python Requests to integrate its functionality into a project of mine.

I'm aware that the form has CSRF protection, so I made sure to include the token as part of the POST request, and yet this wasn't successful, returning a 404 error:

```
from requests import Session
from lxml import html

citations = ["107 F. Scarpa, S. Blain, T. Lew, D. Perrott, M. Ruzzene and J. Yates, Elastic buckling of hexagonal chiral cell honeycombs, Composites, Part A, 2007, 38(2), 280–289"]
s = Session()
url = 'https://anystyle.io/'
page = s.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
csrf_token = tree.xpath("/html/head/meta[4]/@content")[0]
response = s.post(
    headers = {
        'Origin': url,
        'Referer': url,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf_token
    },
    url = url,
    params = (
        ('format', 'json'),
    ),
    json = {
        'input': citations
    },
    cookies = {
        '_any_style_session': s.cookies.get('_any_style_session')
    }
)
response.json()
```

What I'd like to know is whether the CSRF issue is being addressed correctly by the above code to return a successful request, or if the [app](https://github.com/inukshuk/anystyle.io) has been designed in such a way as to prevent automated requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `/parse` to the POST URL:

```
from requests import Session
from lxml import html

citations = ["107 F. Scarpa, S. Blain, T. Lew, D. Perrott, M. Ruzzene and J. Yates, Elastic buckling of hexagonal chiral cell honeycombs, Composites, Part A, 2007, 38(2), 280–289"]
s = Session()
url = 'https://anystyle.io'
page = s.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
csrf_token = tree.xpath("/html/head/meta[4]/@content")[0]
response = s.post(
    headers = {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf_token  # <-- only this header is needed
    },
    url = url + '/parse',           # <-- add '/parse' here!
    params = (
        ('format', 'json'),
    ),
    json = {
        'input': citations
    },
    # cookies= are not needed:
)
print( response.json() )
```

Prints:

```
[[['citation-number', '107'], ['author', 'F.'], ['author', 'Scarpa,'], ['author', 'S.'], ['author', 'Blain,'], ['author', 'T.'], ['author', 'Lew,'], ['author', 'D.'], ['author', 'Perrott,'], ['author', 'M.'], ['author', 'Ruzzene'], ['author', 'and'], ['author', 'J.'], ['author', 'Yates,'], ['title', 'Elastic'], ['title', 'buckling'], ['title', 'of'], ['title', 'hexagonal'], ['title', 'chiral'], ['title', 'cell'], ['title', 'honeycombs,'], ['journal', 'Composites,'], ['journal', 'Part'], ['journal', 'A,'], ['date', '2007,'], ['volume', '38(2),'], ['pages', '280–289']]]
```

Comment: It worked! I'm satisfied that the CSRF issue was being handled correctly and that it was just an issue of sending a request to the wrong url.